# No UIKeyboardWillShowNotification when tapping the next UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have several UITextFields listed below each other and would like to move the active field appropriately when the keyboard slides up.

I have added my controller as an observer to UIKeyboardWillShowNotifications and that works fine when the user first taps a text field. If he taps one of the other text fields without making the keyboard go away first no UIKeyboardWillShowNotifications appears though and I get no chance to adjust the position of the new active text field. I guess it somehow makes sense that no UIKeyboardWillShowNotification appears as the keyboard just stays there but...

What to do??

I do not see how I can add my adjusting code somewhere else as I need the keyboard size information which is kept in the userInfo in the keyboard notification.

Thanks a lot,
Stine

EDIT: Maybe it will be more clear what I need if I paste some of my code here:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cellInputViewWillOpen:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cellInputViewWillClose) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];  
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) cellInputViewWillOpen:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.tableView.contentOffset.x, cell.frame.origin.y - ((self.tableView.frame.size.height - keyboardFrame.size.height) / 2.0f)); 
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, keyboardFrame.size.height - 44.0f, 0.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) cellInputViewWillClose {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    [UIView commitAnimations];     
}
```

---

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the new information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textField:didBeginEditing` instead. You may need to keep track separately of if your keyboard is already showing so you don't scroll twice.

EDIT : I didn't realise you were talking about a table view, sorry. In that case you can adjust the scroll view contents as you are already doing, then use the table view scroll to index path methods when you change the selection using the table view delegate methods.

Comment: But how can I get hold of the keyboard size information in there? :)

Comment: Keep your original code from keyboardwillshow, this is just for your subsequent fields. This is what I meant by keeping track of the keyboard separately, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, if I am slow here, but I don't understand what I will be doing in the `textField:didBeginEditing`?

Comment: You will scroll to the new textfield. Unless I've completely misunderstood the question?

Comment: ARGH! It woooorks!! :D Thank you sooo much!!